# Trouble plotting predict line in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a simple data set with two columns of data- `K` and `SwStr`.

```
K = c(.259, .215, .224, .223, .262, .233)
SwStr = c(.130, .117, .117, .114, .113, .111)
```

I plotted the data using:

```
plot(res$K, res$SwStr)
```

I want to plot the result of a linear model, using `SwStr` to predict `K`. I try to do that using:

```
graphic<-lm(K~SwStr-1, data=res)
P=predict(graphic)

plot(res$K, res$SwStr)
lines(P, lty="dashed", col="green", lwd=3)
```

But when I do this, I don't get any line plotted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to have solved your problem (Yay!) but I thought I'd point out that in your code above you say `plot(res$K, res$SwStr)`, which treats `K` as the `x` values. You probably meant to reverse those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) You are inverting the axes of the original plot.  If you want `SwStr` on the x axis and `K` on the y axis you need

```
plot(res$SwStr, res$K)
```

or

```
with(res,plot(K~SwStr))
```

If you check the actual values of the plotted points on the graph, this might be obvious (especially if `K` and `SwStr` have different magnitudes) ...

For `lm` fits you can also use `abline(graphic,...)`

**edit**: (2) You also have to realize that `predict` gives just the predicted y values, not the x values. So you want something like this:

```
K=c(.259, .215, .224, .223, .262, .233)
SwStr=c(.130, .117, .117, .114, .113, .111)
g <- lm(K~SwStr-1)
par(las=1,bty="l")  ## my favourites
plot(K~SwStr)
P <- predict(g)
lines(SwStr,P)
```

Depending on the situation, you may also want to use the `newdata` argument to `predict` to specify a set of evenly spaced x values ...

Comment: Here is some sample data: K=c(.26,.20,.15,.17) SwStr=c(.15,.12,.07,.11)

Comment: Thanks. Adding the SwStr to the lines argument did the trick. Would you mind elaborating a bit on the functionality of the newdata argument?